# Which Leaflet Basemap with shaded relief should I use for a WebGIS?

Tags: leaflet, basemap, shaded-relief

I'm having difficulties to show shaded relief in our Basemap.

Where can I find a free and clean basemap service, that shows only shaded relief? With no labels, no roads, no rivers, no cities, etc., ready to use my cartographic base.